# issue passing dynamic ID to jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble selecting some elements dynamically with jQuery. This is pretty basic, but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

I've got:

```
var popularItems = ($(rowData[0].items));
for(var i=0;i<popularItems.length;i++){
   var dynId = popularItems[i].id;
   var itemToSelect = $("#"+dynId).children()[0];
   $(itemToSelect).css('display',none');
}
```

When I type in my selector manually into the console, this does work. However, when I console log itemToSelect in this function, it always turns up undefined!

Comment: Check with `console.log($("#"+dynId).length)`

Comment: Ah, $("#"+dynId).length is 0..

Comment: Then element doesn't exists, Share the HTML and `items` with all relevant code

Comment: Most likely that the DOM elements are not ready yet...

Comment: Where have you put this Javascript relative to your HTML markup?